# Как записать разницу между длинами сторон в прямоугольнике c#

Tags: c#

Нужно создать класс "Прямоугольник".
Поля - стороны, разница между длинами сторон.
Метод - найти площадь.
Не могу понять как записать разницу между длинами сторон , подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: В одном кармане 3 рубля, в другом 8. Какова разница? Как узнал? Со сторонами прямоугольника точно так же.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```
a-b;
```

> Achievement achieved: усвоена математика уровня первого класса

или так:

```
Math.Abs(a-b);
```

если нужно результат по-модулю